# Pulling all information on a user from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, primary-key, sessionid

I have two tables `gcm_users` and `vechicle_master` with me.

`gcm_users` has `session id` named **ID** which is generated automatically*(A_I Primary Key)* when user registers.I use this `session id` in my query to identify the user at time of log in.

requirement - i want to show all the vehicle details  from `vehicle_master` table which are related with the user from the `gcm_user` table.

> NOTE:
>   when a user logs in, he should only see his own vehicle details.

Comment: What is the relation between two tables ?

Comment: `select * from vehicle_master where session_id = $user_session_id`?

Comment: but 'session id' is a field from gcm_user table ?!

Comment: @AbdulManaf both tables are connected with a common field 'registration number' which is a unique key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using JOIN you can do like, put your user_id in place of 1

```
SELECT a.*
FROM vehicle_master a 
JOIN gcm_users b
ON a.registration_no = b.registration_no
WHERE user_id =  1
```